# Is this a known combinatorial optimization/scheduling problem?

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, scheduling

We are given $n$ stacks which hold "items" of different colour and a machine that can process multiple items of the same colour in one go. At each step, we can remove *one* item from the *top* of each stack and put it into our machine (so effectively the machine can process at most $n$ items in one step - for that to happen, all stacks must have items of the same colour on top). The goal is to process all items in minimal time.

Example input:

[image]

One possible solution is a greedy algorithm: at each step, just take as much items as possible and stuff them all into the machine. Unfortunately, the greedy algorithm is not optimal - it produces the following schedule for the example input:

[image]

The optimal schedule is the following:

[image]

I plan to go with some form of state space search, but maybe there is a more problem-specific and efficient approach? Links to relevant literature appreciated.

Comment: At each step, you are allowed to take *only one* item from the top of each stack (and all the items you put into machine must be of the same colour). So the greedy algorithm produces a non-optimal schedule (see fig. 2).

Comment: And you must process all items in order, i.e. take them only from the top.

Comment: Ahh. Got it. Interesting problem. I would make an optimal lookup table to decide the first few rows if this were a realtime system. As for exact complexity... prove the optimal for the two column case first.

Comment: The quiestion would be even more interesting, if operating on a set of FIFO lists where you can only peek elements up to particular depth for computation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is equivalent to *Shortest Common Supersequence* (SCS) and was considered in $[1]$ by the name *Scheduling on batch machines with precedence constraints as chains and compatibilities*. If items in the problem are of the same color then such problem is in P and can be solved in $O(n^2)$  $[2]$.

What concerns approximability a good source is *[A compendium of NP optimization problems](https://www.csc.kth.se/%7Eviggo/wwwcompendium/node165.html)*.

The lastest results on SCS can be found in $[3,4]$.

For practical algorithms see $[5]$ whose author states that "Hybrid MA-BS is a current state-of-the-art technique for the SCSP $[6]$ ".

1. Brauner N., Naves G. [Scheduling chains of operations on a batching machine with disjoint sets of operation compatibility](https://hal.science/hal-00264402/).
2. Brucker P. Scheduling algorithms (Chapter 8. Batching Problems).
3. Timkovsky V. G. [Some Approximations for Shortest Common Nonsubsequences and Supersequences](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-89097-3_25).
4. Gotthilf Z. and Lewenstein M. [Improved Approximation Results on the Shortest Common Supersequence Problem](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-03784-9_27).
5. Kubalik J. [Efficient stochastic local search algorithm for solving the shortest common supersequence problem](https://doi.org/10.1145/1830483.1830529).
6. Blum, C., Cotta, C., Fernandez, A. J., Gallardo, J. E. [A Probabilistic Beam Search Approach to the Shortest Common Supersequence Problem](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.75.9732).

Comment: paper [1] contains an observation i was going to write too: when there are $k$ stacks and $n$ items total, there is a dynamic programming solution in time $O(n^k)$

Answer (score 2):

The optimization problems seems to be equivalent to shortest common supersequence as well. The two results I found related to approximating this problem (it is NP-hard in general) are [this](http://epubs.siam.org/sicomp/resource/1/smjcat/v24/i5/p1122_s1) and [this](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=642130). There are some inapproximability results and much weaker approximation results it seems. The [first paper](http://epubs.siam.org/sicomp/resource/1/smjcat/v24/i5/p1122_s1) shows $\Omega(\log^\delta n)$ hardness of approximation and a polynomial factor approximation.

Here is a simple fact (I will use your terminology instead of the shortest common supersequence terminology): if there are $k$ colors, then the greedy algorithm (take the items from the color class that has the most available balls) is a $k$ approximation. Say at some step of the optimal  we take a set $X$ of $|X| = x$ items, and consider the time step in the algorithm when we first took items from $X$. At that time step in the algorithm there were at least $x$ nonempty stacks (since not all $x$ items from $X$ are taken yet) and by averaging the algorithm took at least $x/k$ items. So the problem has a polytime dynamic programming solution when there are constantly many stacks, and a constant greedy approximation when there are constantly many color classes.